# "inline temporary variable" refactor causes build error in VS 2017 default MVC template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, refactoring, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 Community, patched up as of 4/20/2017, I'm seeing an issue in the default MVC ASP.NET template for .net framework 4.6.2.  The 'inline temporary variable' refactoring is suggested.  I apply it and then build and get compiler errors suggesting the compiler doesn't understand the refactored code.

To reproduce the issue: File New -> Visual C# -> Web -> ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework). Choose MVC and no authentication. Inside a method, such as Index() on HomeController, add this:

```
var s = "test";
var q = s as IComparable;
if (q != null) { }
```

Observe the var q is underlined and an inline temporary variable refactor is suggested.  Ctrl+.  (or click lightbulb -> inline temporary variable) results in this code:

```
if (s is IComparableq) { }
```

Build.  Note the compiler errors in the build output suggesting a ) ; or } are omitted on the refactored line. The errors are not shown in the error list, only the output window.  Expected behavior would be that it compiles.

This behavior does not occur for a console app.

I'm guessing this has to do with the default templates using an older compiler version, but I can't figure out where that might be set or how to fix for this project.  Also it seems like the IDE shouldn't recommend a refactor that the current project doesn't support, and that the IDE error list should mirror the build errors.  I've seen other SO posts that are similar, but the suggested fixes (update-package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r, removing lines from the project file) don't seem to work, and the other posts involve different symptoms and older VS versions.

I like the refactored code better and would like to use this feature.  How can I make this work in my ASP.NET Web Application?

Comment: Had similar problem using c#. Submitted https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/49712/ide0020-problem.html